# ServiceInsight Saga View not working

Tags: nservicebus, serviceinsight

See the following screen shot:
[image: saga view not working]

In my endpoint project I have referenced the ServiceControl SagaAudit plugin, such that when I deploy, the necessary dll is deployed as expected.  You can see this in the left pane of the screenshot, which shows a view of the files in my deployed folder, from which the NServiceBus.host.exe is running processing messages successfully.

Yet the Saga view in ServiceInsight is complaining that I don't have the necessary ServiceControl plugin.

What am I missing?

Comment: SO is not the best place to debug these sorts of problems. Please raise an issue at https://github.com/particular/serviceinsight

Comment: Ok, done.  Question closed.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is product-specific, and should be asked on that product's issues forum.

Answer (score 0):

You need the saga audit plugin to see the saga data, see http://docs.particular.net/servicecontrol/plugins/saga-audit for information and links to the nuget packages. be aware that you need to include the assembly to scan in the config:

```
// Create a new configuration
var config = new BusConfiguration();

// Make sure to add the ServiceControl plugin assembly
config.AssembliesToScan(
  AllAssemblies.Matching("NServiceBus").And("ServiceControl.Plugin").ToList()
);
```